# How to get JSON values of multiple keys of the same name

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON data set as follows:

```
{
   "content":[],
   "layout":[],
   "trail":[
      {
         "content":[
            {
               "type":"image",
               "media":[
                  {
                     "type":"image/jpg",
                     "width":593,
                     "height":900,
                     "url":"https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48208920877_e6b234d3ea_c_d.jpg",
                     "flickr":{
                        "flickr-post":"https://www.flickr.com/photos/riketrs/48208920877",
                        "flickr-album":"https://www.flickr.com/photos/riketrs/albums/72157709130951466"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            },
            
            {
               "type":"image",
               "media":[
                  {
                     "type":"image/jpg",
                     "width":1600,
                     "height":900,
                     "url":"https://live.staticflickr.com/2817/33807326532_91013ef6b1_h_d.jpg",
                     "flickr":{
                        "flickr-post":"https://www.flickr.com/photos/146758538@N03/33807326532",
                        "flickr-album":"https://www.flickr.com/photos/146758538@N03/albums/72157681438471236"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         
         "colors":{
            "c0":"#1e1e1d",
            "c1":"#78736f",
            "c2":"#b2a89f"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to `console.log` the `"url"` key for each of the images shown here.
(`https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48208920877_e6b234d3ea_c_d.jpg` and `https://live.staticflickr.com/2817/33807326532_91013ef6b1_h_d.jpg`)

I tried some code but I'm very new to JSON in general, I've looked at some other answers to do with JSON but I'm not quite sure how to achieve what I want.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fj6qveh1/1/

I appreciate all advice, including links to other answers that I potentially missed.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`url` is a property of an object. There can be many of these in a `media` array. (This data only shows one object per array.) `media` itself is an property of objects inside the `content` array.

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

`map` to return the URL values from the objects in `media`, and `flatMap` to return a flat array of the nested arrays returned by `map`.

```js
const data={content:[],layout:[],trail:[{content:[{type:"image",media:[{type:"image/jpg",width:593,height:900,url:"https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48208920877_e6b234d3ea_c_d.jpg",flickr:{"flickr-post":"https://www.flickr.com/photos/riketrs/48208920877","flickr-album":"https://www.flickr.com/photos/riketrs/albums/72157709130951466"}}]},{type:"image",media:[{type:"image/jpg",width:1600,height:900,url:"https://live.staticflickr.com/2817/33807326532_91013ef6b1_h_d.jpg",flickr:{"flickr-post":"https://www.flickr.com/photos/146758538@N03/33807326532","flickr-album":"https://www.flickr.com/photos/146758538@N03/albums/72157681438471236"}},{type:"image/jpg",width:1600,height:900,url:"https://live.dummyimage.com/2817/dummy.jpg",flickr:{"flickr-post":"https://www.flickr.com/photos/146758538@N03/33807326532","flickr-album":"https://www.flickr.com/photos/146758538@N03/albums/72157681438471236"}}]}],colors:{c0:"#1e1e1d",c1:"#78736f",c2:"#b2a89f"}}]};

const content = data.trail[0].content;

const urls = content.flatMap(obj => {
  return obj.media.map(inner => inner.url);
});

console.log(urls)
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation! ✧٩(•́⌄•́๑)

Comment: And what if trail have no elements or have multiple

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `map` function. Given that you are very new to programming (the solution has little to do with JSON itself, since the first step is to parse JSON string to a JavaScript object), it would be better if you try yourself. But you start with

```
let urls = trail["content"].map(x => x["media"][0]["url"])
```

for more about `map` function look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: thank you! map sounds like a cool function, will definitely look into that. cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is a table in the table so for each table:

```
for(let i in trail){    
    var content = trail[i]["content"];
  content.forEach(content => content.media.forEach(media => console.log(media.url)))
}
```

Comment: did not they were called `tables`. thanks a lot gringo!

Answer (score 0):

To access object properties, you can use a dot (`.`), and to access an array element, you use its index in square brackets (`[]`). So you just keep repeating these steps as necessary until you get to the content you're looking for.

Here's how that looks on a simplified version of your object, using the `forEach` method of arrays to apply a custom function to each item in the `content` array:

```js
const json = getJson();
json.trail[0].content.forEach(item=>console.log(item.media[0].url));

function getJson(){
  let obj = {
    "trail": [{
      "content": [
        { "media": [{ "url":"image #65535/48208920877_e6b234d3ea_c_d.jpg" }]},
        { "media": [{"url":"image #2817/33807326532_91013ef6b1_h_d.jpg"}]}
      ]
    }]
  };
  return obj;
}
```